# Why can't I see my spark job on port 4040 even though I see it running in the yarn UI?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

It was my understanding that we can always see spark jobs at port 4040 on the master node.

I am running spark on yarn, and I'm running a job through spark submit.  When I go into the yarn UI, I am able to see that the job is `RUNNING`, and when I go to the spark master at `<master ip>:18081` then I can see that the spark job is picked up by the master in the history server.

(and of course I do not see it runing at `<master ip>:18080` because I'm not running in standalone).
However, I am not able to see the job running at port 4040 in the yarn UI.
[image]
The job does not fail - it just hangs for forever.  And I can see that my workers are alive in the spark master UI.

This is the resource utilization shown by yarn while it is running:

How do I fix this to show that my spark job is running, or at least give me some feedback on whether or not my job is progressing?

Comment: What does the `YarnApplicationState` message read?

Comment: it reads, `RUNNING`, like I said in the question.

Comment: Make sure that all required ports are accessible on all the systems and if possible try after disabling the firewall & reloading to make sure it's not the culprit.

Comment: thank you, @AsheshKumarSingh, can you be more specific?  I'm not familiar with how to do that, thanks.

Comment: You basically need to make sure that the firewall is allowing the connection on required ports by configuring`IPTABLES` or whatever that your system is using. This could be just one of the reasons the job is stuck.

Comment: well, FWIW I've never had any trouble with other clusters running spark jobs while connected to this network.  I've always been able to view them at port `4040`.  So, I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: Alright, have you tweaked the resource usage limits and what is their utilisation while in this `RUNNING` state?

Comment: I showed the resource utilization in my question. thanks.

Comment: What about free disk space?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151963/discussion-between-hunle-and-ashesh-kumar-singh).